# Is there any way to know when was my iPad updated to the latest version of iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad

I would like to see the OS update history in my iPad, as in when and at what time did I install a specific iOS update in my device.

Is there any way to see that?

Answer (score -1):

IOS differs from macOS.
macOS updates the OS via App Store. And App Store keeps tracking what we have updated.
Unfortunately, iOS updates via Software Update in Settings. And it doas not keep history of the updates. I think there is no workaround at the moment. And I think iTunes login can't help in this case.